# Upgrade from 18.04 to 20.04 with raid1 lvm boot error waiting for device /dev/md1

Tags: raid, do-release-upgrade

I upgraded my ubuntu server form 18.04 to 20.04 and now I get the following error during boot:

```
[ TIME ] Timed out waiting for device /dev/md1
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for mnt/md1
```

I setup raid1 on ubuntu 18 that was working fine. I can still SSH into the server and run commands but the monitor on the server is stuck on the above error.

I've read a lot of posts and can't figure out what to do. I noticed my UUIDs are the same for both drives and that might be an issue? Here is some info:

```
~$ lsblk -f
NAME          FSTYPE            LABEL         UUID                                   FSAVAIL FSUSE% MOUNTPOINT
loop0         squashfs                                                                     0   100% /snap/snapd/20290
loop1         squashfs                                                                     0   100% /snap/lxd/24061
loop2         squashfs                                                                     0   100% /snap/core20/2015
sda
├─sda1        vfat                            E23E-01B3
└─sda2        linux_raid_member mypc:0        febc2d66-d036-8732-0647-9ef774a9c450
  └─md0       LVM2_member                     4AgQTj-zcr5-DJdl-R2h7-R32O-rfVY-0pphnU
    ├─vg-swap swap                            2432e24c-7852-499c-aa1f-8483120393f5                  [SWAP]
    ├─vg-root ext4                            b923aec1-8737-4d7b-b2ad-aed2ef8dff9b     77.2G    10% /
    ├─vg-tmp  ext4                            da098742-230b-4d98-b532-afcee84ab0b1     43.2G     0% /tmp
    ├─vg-var  ext4                            8b605aca-3f9d-4f2f-b734-e61a6fd1b843     14.1G    33% /var
    └─vg-home ext4                            ee4d57a5-481c-48a1-afcb-5ecc9f89cf94      2.2T    52% /home
sdb
├─sdb1        vfat                            E23E-01B3                               945.1M     1% /boot/efi
└─sdb2        linux_raid_member mypc:0        febc2d66-d036-8732-0647-9ef774a9c450
  └─md0       LVM2_member                     4AgQTj-zcr5-DJdl-R2h7-R32O-rfVY-0pphnU
    ├─vg-swap swap                            2432e24c-7852-499c-aa1f-8483120393f5                  [SWAP]
    ├─vg-root ext4                            b923aec1-8737-4d7b-b2ad-aed2ef8dff9b     77.2G    10% /
    ├─vg-tmp  ext4                            da098742-230b-4d98-b532-afcee84ab0b1     43.2G     0% /tmp
    ├─vg-var  ext4                            8b605aca-3f9d-4f2f-b734-e61a6fd1b843     14.1G    33% /var
    └─vg-home ext4                            ee4d57a5-481c-48a1-afcb-5ecc9f89cf94      2.2T    52% /home


~$ cat /etc/fstab
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
/dev/mapper/vg-root /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=E23E-01B3  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
/dev/mapper/vg-home /home           ext4    defaults        0       2
/dev/mapper/vg-tmp /tmp            ext4    defaults        0       2
/dev/mapper/vg-var /var            ext4    defaults        0       2
/dev/mapper/vg-swap none            swap    sw              0       0
/dev/md1 /mnt/md1 ext4 defaults,nofail,discard 0 0

~$ cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [raid1] [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10]
md0 : active raid1 sdb2[1] sda2[0]
      5859412992 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]
      bitmap: 1/44 pages [4KB], 65536KB chunk

unused devices: <none>


~$ cat /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf
# mdadm.conf
#
# !NB! Run update-initramfs -u after updating this file.
# !NB! This will ensure that initramfs has an uptodate copy.
#
# Please refer to mdadm.conf(5) for information about this file.
#

# by default (built-in), scan all partitions (/proc/partitions) and all
# containers for MD superblocks. alternatively, specify devices to scan, using
# wildcards if desired.
#DEVICE partitions containers

# automatically tag new arrays as belonging to the local system
HOMEHOST <system>

# instruct the monitoring daemon where to send mail alerts
MAILADDR root

# definitions of existing MD arrays
ARRAY /dev/md/0  metadata=1.2 UUID=febc2d66:d0368732:06479ef7:74a9c450 name=mypc:0

ARRAY /dev/md1 metadata=1.2 name=mypc:1 UUID=472411d9:f517c8d8:0d6c26da:15a53b24
```

Comment: I commented out the ARRAY /dev/md1 from mdadm.conf and no longer get the error for that raid array. HOWEVER, the server doesn't reach the terminal, I tried reinstalling KDE thinking that perhaps it is expecting the GUI that I had briefly added and removed but it doesn't load KDE either. 

I can still SSH to the server and use the terminal to make changes that way, all my data is there as well (md0).

Comment: Look carefully at the last 2 lines of your question. See anything unusual about md0?